Acceptance of n length word that is accepted by Turing Machine in m steps
let x a word with length of n an it is accepted by Turing machine in m steps.
I think that if m<=n, there would be infinite number of words (all the words that starts with x) that are accepted by Turing machine in at most m steps because the movement of the head in work tape is limited by the length of the word thus it is not able to read the symbol at n+1 or more. If m>n the movement of head can exceed the length of the   word so wether x.w will be accepted or not is not decidable and we do not know in general if infinite number of words will be accepted by this Turing machine. Would my intuition be correct?

Sure. If a Turing machine terminates in $m$ steps, then it would behave the same if the tape was changed outside of the first $m$ cells in either direction.
